# Java Interacting with CMD

Tags: java, android, sign

I am trying out how to interact with Command Prompt via Java .

From CMD , i usually execute the following commands:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore d1.keystore -alias sample -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000 

jarsigner -verbose -keystore d1.keystore ad.apk sample
```

However , after the exution of the first command , from the cmd promopt i am required to enter the password .

I am able to execute command via

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(x)//set command as x
```

but i cant figure out how to enter the password.

Thanks.

How can i return this value from my Java app?

Thanks.

Comment: Add option `-keypass KEYPASS`.

Comment: @saka1029  hi I asking about how to interact with cmd..  not on signing the apk..  thanks